# Android wifi device communication on same router

Tags: android, wifi, chat

I am working on an application, where I need to send and receive message on device connected with same router.

Initially i used peer to peer for this. and it is working fine. But my client requirement changed now. he don't want wifi P2P. He want direct communication between device that are connected on same wifi connection or router.

So Is it possible to send and get text between two device connected on same wifi network?

Comment: If you have no problem description and no questions then i wonder why you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not leverage sockets? There is a library called AndroidAsync by koush that will let you create sockets that will listen for data?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, unless your access point doesn't use a Client Isolation mode, when clients of the same WiFi AP cannot communicate with each other.

Client isolation has been used by the public WiFi APs quite frequently.